# Does heteroskedasticity matter when estimating a regression using the entire population?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, sampling, inference

The F-statistic, t-statistics, p-values and standard errors of the estimated coefficients will all be incorrect in the presence of heteroskedasticity.

However, does this even matter if I am working on a dataset that covers the entire population of interest given that I have no need to generalize beyond the present dataset.

Comment: What do you mean by "covers the entire population of interest?" If you really have the entire population (all *possible* data), then statistical tests are meaningless.

Comment: It's not an estimate any more, so none of that stuff matters, as you suspect.